# Darwin Streaming Server and iPhone streaming

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to configure iPhone streaming (HTTP Live Streaming) on Darwin Streaming Server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but it's not specifically for iPhone, it's just a regular H.264 in an mp4 wrapper streamed over https, only the resolution is specific, if you want it to be, to iPhone.